Is it possible to improve the rising-slope of a buck DCDC converter?
I designed a DCDC converter that accepts an input voltage between 14 V and 18 V and outputs 3.3 V. Here the schematic:

It works fine but I had a problem with a couple of sensors. The manufacturer said they need a rising slope of at least 10 V/ms. Here the actual rising slope of the +3V3 rail on my board:

it's far longer than the requested timing.
Since the sensors draw a very little current (less than 1 uA) I can use a MOSFET or even just a GPIO line of my MCU to power them after the main power supply has stabilized - and this should be enough to stay in the limits.
However, I wonder if there is anything I could do to improve the rising-slope on my current prototype to make the sensors work in the meanwhile I run a second batch.
This is the sensor's section of the circuit:


Could you afford a P MOSFET in the power rail of your sensors?

@winny, yes as I've already suggested in my own question. But I'm afraid about the I2C pull-ups. Would not they power the sensors while the MOSFET is still off? I guess I need to put also them after the transistor.

If the load is light you could reduce the converter output capacitor.

Create 3V3_SWITCHED rail behind your P-MOSFET and use it for both pull-up for I2C and Vcc?

Did you consider to switch sensor GND via GPIO to avoid pullup resistor trouble?

Yes, it is possible to improve, but the regulator cannot meet 10V/ms rate.
You have selected a 33nF soft-start capacitor, which as per the datasheet converts to 4.2ms startup time. Based on your scope diagram, it's almost spot on 4.2ms startup time, meaning slew rate is 0.786V/ms.
You could change to a smaller capacitor for faster start time, but there is a catch.
Datasheet also says minimum capacitance is 6.8nF for about 1ms startup time. And 3.3V in 1ms still is not enough, you need 3.3V rise in 0.33 milliseconds.
So changing the startup capacitor will still not make the regulator meet the target of 10V/ms, not even if the output capacitor is made smaller.
If you do power the sensors from an IO pin, or otherwise switch the 3.3V supply to the chip with some method, the pull-up resistors must be on the sensor side of the supply switch, not on the MCU side.
